# How to determine what unit is used?

Tags: unit-of-measure

I'm using a working template containing this line below and am wondering what unit is used? I'd expect at least e.g. `3.18pt` to be necessary.

```
\vspace{3.18\baselineskip}
```

Comment: `\baselineskip` is already a "length" and contains the units inside it! If you use something else like a number or a variable that is a number you HAVE to include the units too inside the `\vspace` command as you expect. PS:You can print its value by using the command `\the\baselineskip`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The control sequence `\baselineskip` in that context denotes “whatever value is currently stored in the parameter `\baselineskip`”.

Internally this is just a number, but it's convenient to think it as expressed in unit `pt`.

So you are asking TeX to multiply that length by the factor 3.18; if `\baselineskip` happens to be 12pt, the result will be a vertical space of 38.16pt.

Comment: In conclusion I understood `if only a digit is used, pt is the (default) unit`, is that correct? Grepping through the complete file didn't reveal any baselineskip <> pt relation

Comment: @AikenCura No, `pt` is not implied as a default: `\baselineskip` refers to a length and it's immaterial if it is stored in points, millimeters or yards. You're just multiplying that length by 3.18.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by egreg's perfect answer, maybe the following code is useful to you ([using the **printlen** package](https://ctan.org/pkg/printlen)).

```
\documentclass{article}

% https://ctan.org/pkg/printlen
\usepackage{printlen}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[textwidth (mm)] \uselengthunit{mm}\printlength{\textwidth}
\item[textwidth (in)] \uselengthunit{in}\printlength{\textwidth}
\item[baselineskip (pt)] \uselengthunit{pt}\printlength{\baselineskip}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

[image]

*(Taken from the [printlen manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/printlen), version 2009-09-03).*

Comment: Also package `printlen` can be useful, in general, to print the current value of any length parameter.

Comment: @lacobus1983 Thanks! This is (of course) much better. I have updated the answer accordingly.